# Is it possible to acquire level 4 limit without having level 3?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In Final Fantasy VII, is it possible to get Lvl. 4 limit breaks without unlocking the lower levels?

Answer (score 5):

Yes and No you can unlock level 4 without fully unlocking all your limit breaks. For most characters (with the exception of Vincent and Cait Sith) there are 7 limit breaks. The first level in levels 1 to 3 are unlocked by how many enemies you have killed with that character.

For example take a look at Clouds table to gain limits from [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/16441)

```
Cloud Strife

Limit 1/1: Braver         | Used 8 times to learn Limit 1/2: CrossSlash

Limit 1/2: CrossSlash    | 120 kills made to learn Limit 2/1: Blade Beam

Limit 2/1: Blade Beam     | Used 7 times to learn Limit 2/2: Climhazzard

Limit 2/2: Climhazzard    | 200 kills made to learn Limit 3/1: Meteorain

Limit 3/1: Meteorain      | Used 6 times to learn Limit 3/2: Finishing Touch

Limit 3/2: Finishing Touch| Omnislash manual used to teach Limit 4/1: Omnislash

Limit 4/1: Omnislash      | All limits learned.
```

If you have 120 kills you will learn Limit 2/1, without ever using your limit break with cloud you will unlock level 1/2. If once again you make 200 kills with Cloud with out ever using 2/1 you will unlock 3/1.  Now to learn Level 4/1 you would need to get 3/2, but it is possible to never learn 1/2 or 2/2 limit breaks.

Comment: From the linked article: "Level 4 limits may only be taught to a character after that character has learned all of his/her previous limit breaks."

Comment: Its not correct, please try it, what it means is you must learn 3/2.

Comment: I will try it out and add proof if I can get it to happen. I will make sure Aeris doesn't learn 2/2 "Fury Brand"

Comment: I can confirm this, my first ever playthrough of the game I was able to use level 4 limits without unlock 1/2 and/or 2/2 (back then I didn't understand how they were unlocked and missed them). 3/2 eventually became unlocked purely because I couldn't use the level 4 item yet!

Answer (score 4):

Not according to this information I've found:

- [FF7 Limit Breaks on FF Shrine](http://www.ffshrine.org/ff7/ff7_limits.php)
- [FF7 Limit Break Mechanics on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/16441)

It appears the L4 limit breaks require you to have all previous limits.